# WiX 3.6 Bundle shown in Add Remove Programs after chained .net4 installed, but user cancelled

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

Using WiX 3.6, I have a custom .NET BootstrapperApplication where I've included the .Net 4.0 web installer in the chain:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="$(var.BundleProductName)"
      Version="$(var.BundleVersion)"
...
      Compressed="yes" DisableRepair="yes" >

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
      <PayloadGroupRef Id="MyInstallerUILibs" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <!-- Install .Net 4 Full -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />

      <!-- Install my packages -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="MyPackages" />

    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

When I run the installer on a machine without .net 4 installed, it prompts
the user to download as expected and correctly installs .net 4.0 before
displaying my custom UI. So far, so good.

In my UI, I want to give the user the option of cancelling/exiting the
install before we install any additional packages. For example, if the user
doesn't agree to our EULA.

**What I'm seeing is this:** If the .net 4.0 install runs and completes, then
within my BootstrapperApplication I exit before doing any Plan/Apply
actions, the bundle still shows up in the Windows Add/Remove Programs menu. I've
tried calling `Engine.Quit((int) ActionResult.NotExecuted)` and
`Engine.Quit((int) ActionResult.UserExit)`, but neither seem to keep it off
the ARP list.

Note: the .net 4 install is also shown in the APR list, as expected.

**And my question is this:**
What is the right way to signal to the WiX engine that the bundle install was
stopped and the bundle itself should not be displayed in the Add/Remove Programs list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn registers itself in ARP as soon as a chain begins, so users can, for example, reinstall a chain that failed partway through without failing the entire chain. The CLR is installed as part of your bundle's chain from the pre-req BA (since your BA can't load until the CLR is installed).